# Is it possible to share a virtual keyboard with multiple textboxes?

Tags: javascript

I've got a **screen** keyboard that I want to share with 3 textboxes. If the user clicks input button "A", the focus as well as all of the keypresses should go into the "A" textbox. If the user presses the "B" input button, then the focus and the keys pressed should go into the "B" textbox. Is this possible? I can't seem to understand how this should work. I'm a total noob to javascript so please, examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to listen to the keypress on the body element. Determine which key it is, then update the focus and the value of the appropriate textbox. Events in javascript bubble up. So if you listen for say keyup on the body, any key press on any element will bubble up to there (unless something along the way cancels it).

**Edit:**
Some code:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
function process(event)
{
   if (event.keyCode == 65) // "a"
   {
       document.getElementById("a").focus();
   }
}
</script>
<body onkeyup="process(event)">
...
</body>
...
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, I need to listen on the `<body>` tag? This isn't possible the way that I have the html laid out in functions. The same body tag is shared out for all of my html pages. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: @Aishwar, if my memory serves me correctly, `event.keyCode` doesn't work in firefox or Chrome, correct?

Comment: @Jim: This does work in IE and FF (so probably Chrome as well..don't have it here, so can't check now)

Comment: I am not sure how you have things set up, but on your page generation code, you can embed the logic to determine whether to add the event handler or not.

Comment: @Aishwar, Yes, you're correct, it does work in both FF and Chrome. I'm sure I can modify my function to use the body element. Is there a more elegant way of attaching or listening for the keyCodes than on the body element?

Comment: You can attach event handlers in other ways as well. You can get the element it self and then set `element.onload=methodName` or you can use the attachEvent in IE and addEventListener in FF. Here is a good link to read more about them: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: @Aishwar, thanks man, you are really being helpful! I'm trying to modify your code but am having some trouble. I've got 3 textboxes as I mentioned but I'm having an issue sending the key presses to the correct box. The user will click an anchor tag and not an input. I'm sorry, I know I said input button, my bad. How will I handle this?

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter if it is an input or anchor, right? I can just use an id in the anchor, correct?

Comment: Oh. I think I misunderstood what you said. If you want this to happen on clicking anchors, then you can register the onclick on the anchor. Something like this: `<a href="#" onclick="process">A-button</a>`. You could have done the same for input text boxes as well (you don't have to register on the body element)

Comment: @Aishwar, would you mind if I posted what I have so far up top? I still can't seem to get this working.